# problems using webkit libs in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, webkit

I tried using [this example](http://tom-shelton.net/?p=95) to create a wrapper for the webkit library. But, when I try to use the method, in c#, from the compiled c++ dll, I get an "method inaccessible due to it's protection level" error.

The method I'm trying to get to is

```
CG_EXTERN CGColorSpaceRef CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(void) CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

as defined in the lib's header.

Comment: My answer wasn't to put you down or anything. I tried the very same thing as you do, and then I realized that wrapping the WebKit-library is a whole lot of work. If you're doing this in your line of work (i.e. you have a dead line), I sincerely recommend using the WebKit.NET project's assemblies. There's a ton of work to do anyway. Also, you get the bug fixes "for free" (and you can submit your own bug reports and/or fixes to the project, as a way of saying "thank you". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project called WebKit.NET: http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ Why not use it instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: The easiest way to use it, is to use their binary distribution. Compiling it from sources is somewhat time consuming. :)

Comment: Binary distribution it is. One small problem when I try to initialize a WebKitBrowser. When building the application, everything seems ok. But when trying to run it, I get an "Failed to initialize activation context" error. Any advice?

Comment: Figured it out in the end. It's a goof wrapper. Now let's see if it works for me.

Comment: What was the cause of the "Failed to initialize activation context" error? I'm getting this as well.